# Unable to run webpack-dev-server on react-native-web. ERROR: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type

Tags: reactjs, react-native, webpack, babeljs, react-native-web

I am trying to dive into React ecosystem and having issues with using `react-native-web` with my React Native Application. I have hosted the application on https://github.com/thedarklord1/testNativeWithWeb. I have used Redux Store and React Native to build a very simple POC to build a calculator. The Android and the iOS versions are executing as expected. The issue that I am facing is that, while trying to run `webpack-dev-server`, to use `react-native-web` for web, it is failing with the error

```
ERROR in ./src/App.js
Module parse failed: /Users/abhishekkumar/Desktop/Credifiable/front_end/testNativeWithWeb/src/App.js Unexpected token (9:6)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|   render() {

|     return (
|       <Provider store={store}>
|         <AppContainer/>
|       </Provider>
 @ ./index.web.js 1:0-28
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 webpack/hot/dev-server ./index.web.js
```

I am fairly new to the React and WebPack ecosystem and any help or pointer is appreciated. TIA.

EDIT: 
I am using the command `webpack-dev-server -d --config web/webpack.config.js --inline --hot --colors` to run the server.

Comment: share your webpack and package.json

Comment: Hey Vikram, webpack config and package.json, both I have put up at https://github.com/thedarklord1/testNativeWithWeb

Comment: try to install npm install babel-preset-es2015    and then configure babel-loader as      {
    test: /\.jsx?$/,
    loader: 'babel-loader',
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    query: {
        presets: ['es2015']
    }
}

Comment: seems like something is wrong with babel-loader configuration.Also try changing test: to  test: /\.jsx?$/,  in babelloaderconfiguration

Comment: Will definitely give it a shot, and get back with findings. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to transpile to es2015 since most of the browsers do not natively understand modern JS.

```
loaders: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            query: {
                presets: ['es2015', 'stage-0', 'react']
            }
        }
    ]
```

Add a loader to your webpack config. It should work then.

Comment: This, plus don't forget to actually install the loaders as npm packages.

Comment: Is this still relevant in 2023? I'm running into issues getting webpack 5 to work with react native web.

Answer (score 3):

In your package.json replace the script tag with

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
  },
```

and install "webpack-dev-server --hot" using npm install webpack-dev-server --hot

And run your app using

```
npm start
```

Also you need to enclose your code in  tag inside return as

```
 render() {

     return (
<div>
       <Provider store={store}>
         <AppContainer/>
       </Provider>
</div>
```

and make sure you have installed all the babel dependencies to compile your code

Comment: Hey Vikram, This is not the answer that I am looking for. Your solution does not solve my problem. Thanks!